# addgoogle map container in boostrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I am trying to add google maps to website, i would like the map to be 100% of the width, i have tried the following code

```
<section class="bg-primary text-white mb-0" id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white">Map</h2>
    <div id="map" style="height=450px"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

i have added

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>
```

and js code

```
function myMap() {
  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myCenter});

marker.setMap(map);
}
```

This literally works randomly, once it shows map ( but map is not 100% width and once not, how can i fix this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

create map element in html like this or add css

```
 <div id="map" style="height:450px;width:100%"></div>

#map{
   width:100%;
}
```